# Failed to DE serialize data for topic to AVRO Using Azure Blob Managed Sink Connector

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-blob-storage, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to launch an Azure Blob Sink Connector in Confluent Cloud for an AVRO topic which is ending up getting a DE serialize error.

The same topic is being used to supply data via the Snowflake Sink Connector and the pipeline runs fine without any errors. The problem occurs only for the Azure Blob Sink Connector, where the connector shows in the running state but all the messages go into DLQ.

It has also been observed that the connector runs fine and the data gets processed if the file format is JSON without schema.

Below are the cluster details:

```
Confluent Cluster Type: Dedicated
Region: East US2
Topic File Format: AVRO
Schema Registry: Enabled
Connector Type: Azure Blob Sink Connector
```

The connector configuration looks like the below JSON

```
{
  "topics": "<topic>",
  "input.data.format": "AVRO",
  "connector.class": "AzureBlobSink",
  "name": "AVRO_Blob_Sink_Connector",
  "kafka.auth.mode": "SERVICE_ACCOUNT",
  "kafka.service.account.id": "<SA-ID>",
  "azblob.account.name": "********************",
  "azblob.account.key": "****************************************************************************************",
  "azblob.container.name": "dev-dl",
  "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH",
  "topics.dir": "topics",
  "time.interval": "DAILY",
  "az.compression.type": "none",
  "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "-1",
  "file.delim": "-",
  "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
  "flush.size": "1000",
  "timezone": "UTC",
  "locale": "en",
  "value.converter.connect.meta.data": "true",
  "max.poll.interval.ms": "300000",
  "max.poll.records": "500",
  "tasks.max": "3"
}
```

Any leads on how this can be resolved?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: The error is "Failed to De Serialize data for the topic to AVRO".  By the way, I was able to figure it out! The issue concerns the connector configuration provided by Confluent for Azure Blob Sink. For Schema Registry, this connector comes with a default configuration setting of None, whereas the data we have flowing into the connector is Backward Compatible. Hence, the messages go to DLQ. I had words with folks from Confluent and they promised to come back with some solutions/alternatives.

Comment: Strange. The compatibility level should be enforced at the registry server, not per connector